# Limit a.s. of a sequence of normal random variables is normal.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, reference-request

I know that the statement

> "If $X_n$ is a sequence of normal random variables which converges a.s. to a random variable $X$, then $X$ is also a normal random variable"

is true. However, do you know a book which has the proof. I am actually looking *not for the proof itself but for a book containing a complete proof*. Thank you for your advice!